# Explicitly output JSON null in case of missing optional value

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Consider this example using Play's JSON API (`play.api.libs.json`):

```
case class FooJson(
   // lots of other fields omitted
   location: Option[LocationJson]
)

object FooJson {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[FooJson]
}
```

and

```
case class LocationJson(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

object LocationJson {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[LocationJson]
}
```

If `location` is `None`, the resulting JSON won't have `location` field at all. This is fine and understadable. But if I wanted for some reason (say, to make my API more self-documenting), **how can I explicitly output `null` in JSON**?

```
{      
  "location": null
}
```

I also tried defining the field as `location: LocationJson` and passing `option.orNull` to it, but it does not work (`scala.MatchError: null` at  `play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2.writes`). For non-custom types such as String or Double, this approach *would* produce null in JSON output.

So, **while using `Json.writes[FooJson]`** as shown above (or something equally simple, i.e. *not* having to write a custom `Writes` implementation), is there a clean way to include nulls in JSON?

What I'm asking is analogous to `JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS` in the Jackson library (also Jackson's default behaviour). Similarly [in Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support) this would be trivial
 (`new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()`).

Play 2.4.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Greg Methvin, a Play committer, [wrote this answer](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4143#issuecomment-165605837) to me in a related GitHub issue:

> The JSON macros only support one way of encoding optional values,
>   which is to omit None values from the JSON. This is not a bug but
>   rather a limitation of the implementation. If you want to include
>   nulls you're unfortunately going to have to implement your own `Writes`.
>
> I do think we should try to provide more configurability for the
>   macros though.

In this case, I'll let Play exclude this field when the value is null, even if it slightly sacrifices API consistency and self-documentability. It's still such a minor thing (in this particular API) that it doesn't warrant uglifying the code as much as a custom `Writes` would take for a case class with a dozen values.

I'm hoping they do make this more configurable in future Play versions.

Answer (score 3):

Hello from the future.

As of Play 2.7, a fairly simple solution was introduced for automated JSON codecs. We can introduce the appropriate implicit value for `JsonConfiguration` in the scope for the `Format`/`Reads`/`Writes`. The following configuration will write `null`s for empty `Option`s instead of omitting the fields entirely.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(optionHandlers = OptionHandlers.WritesNull)
implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
```

[Reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Customize-the-macro-to-output-null)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
object MyWrites extends DefaultWrites{

  override def OptionWrites[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]): Writes[Option[T]] = new Writes[Option[T]] {
    override def writes(o: Option[T]): JsValue = {
      o match {
        case Some(a) => Json.toJson(a)(fmt)
        case None => JsNull
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will overwrite the default implementation which will not create an element. I used this in your sample code:

```
case class FooJson(
                // ...
                location: Option[LocationJson]
              )

case class LocationJson(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

object LocationJson {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[LocationJson]
}

implicit val fooJsonWriter: Writes[FooJson] = new Writes[FooJson] {
  override def writes(o: FooJson): JsValue = {
    JsObject(Seq(
      "location" -> Json.toJson(o.location)
      // Additional fields go here.
    ))
  }
}

Json.toJson(FooJson(None))
```

And got this result `res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"location":null}`.

Comment: Thanks. From the question: "*while using `Json.writes` as shown above (or something equally simple)*" What I tried to say is that a custom `Writes` implementation is not really simple or clean. In my real code that class has 10+ other fields, and it gets ugly having to do what `Json.writes[FooJson]` does automatically.

Comment: I see. If you don't mind I'll try to work on something else and then remove my answer if I can't come up with something better.

Answer (score -2):

if we have null values then we have to add the option with members in case class which will resolve the issue

```
case class response(
 name:String,
 age: option[int]
)

 object response {
    implicit val format = Json.format[response]
  }
```

Here the option is the answer for us. and if we are the JSON response for age is coming as null and this will handle the solution for us.