# Can't use case class to convert JSON key:value pair when value is empty

Tags: json, scala, playframework

In my Play+Scala (2.5.x, 2.11.11) application I am using Case classes to convert JSON to and from (client<->application and application<->DB). Using inbuilt Reads/Writes the conversion becomes completely automatic.
The issue comes when DB returns a `null` value for a field and the corresponding JSON output does not include that key:value pair. For example:

```
def getUserDetails (id: Option[String]) = Action.async {
      dbch.dbProd.withConnection { implicit connection =>
         val result: Option[SignupUserDetails] =
            SQL"""select * from #$USR_LISTUSERS where (User_Pk = ${id})""".as(SignupUserDetailsParser.singleOpt)
         ......
      }
}
```

Case class:

```
case class SignupUserDetails(User_Pk: Option[String], Emailid: Option[String], First_Name: Option[String], Last_Name: Option[String], Country: Option[String])
```

Parser:

```
implicit val SignupUserDetailsParser = Macro.namedParser[SignupUserDetails]
```

I found a similar question where it is mentioned that this behaviour should occur only for custom types but not for `String`  type:
[Explicitly output JSON null in case of missing optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317253/explicitly-output-json-null-in-case-of-missing-optional-value)

But it does not work for String type as well.

Comment: Can you provide some of error logs?

Comment: There is no error. The output JSON value simply will not have that key:value pair in the resulted JSON object. Example below:
{
  "User_Pk": "A0000000000782",
  "Emailid": "abc@abc.com",
  "First_Name": "Nikhil",
  "Last_Name": "Kumar"
}
If the 'Country' column value in null in DB, the resulting JSON string will not have that key:value pair at all.

Comment: Not having the JSON field should be interpreted the same way as if field is explicitly `null`, so what's the purpose to force the second (verbose) form?

Comment: Having the key present (irrespective) in the JSON received by the client provides a much cleaner implementation on the client-side as the JSON keys are guaranteed to be present (just run a loop and accordingly render the values on the UI).